# Setting player for m3u8 playlist by javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I am learning javafx and have problem with setting player for m3u8 playlist.
Are these specs supported?

```
EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1760000,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.66.31,mp4a.40.2",VIDEO="high"
```

My code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main  extends Application{

MediaPlayer mp;

public static void main(String[] args){
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage window) throws Exception {

    Media media = new Media("http://video-edge-c67e90.cdg02.hls.ttvnw.net/hls-80ed1c/monstercat_23008434304_506694841/high/index-live.m3u8?token=id=4715075617224103768,bid=23008434304,exp=1472395154,node=video-edge-c67e90.cdg02,nname=video-edge-c67e90.cdg02,fmt=high&sig=69140c2ba0db19f25820013a5ce6087de0571423");
    mp = new MediaPlayer(media);
    VBox lay = new VBox();
    mp.setAutoPlay(true);

    MediaView mv = new MediaView(mp);

    lay.getChildren().add(mv);
    Scene scene = new Scene(lay,500,500);
    window.setScene(scene);
    window.show();

}
}
```

This code returns window with white background and nothing happens. The link I used works fine in VLC.

//edit the link expire now.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for my question. The problem was with codecs. JavaFX doesn't support this type of media.

I used **vlcj** and now I can play this type of media.